# Cannot call column names inside a function

Tags: r

I know this question has been beat into the ground, but I am having trouble getting a function that calls a column name to work in *my* function. The SO answers I've seen all seem to be workarounds for different solutions (like aes_string for ggplot calls), but I am trying to use a niche function from akima. I am pretty sure that the desired column is being called correctly for the "select" call, but when it gets to "interp" I don't think it likes the argument as a string:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(akima)

heat_map <- function(map){
  
  data1 <- mtcars %>%
    select(mpg, cyl, map) %>%
    with(
      akima::interp(
        mpg, cyl, map,
        duplicate = "mean"
      )
    )
  
  data2 <- data.frame(expand.grid(mpg = data1$x, cyl = data1$y), fill = c(data1$z))
  
  return(data2)
}

wt <- heat_map("wt")
```

And I get the error: `Error in interp(mpg, cyl, map, duplicate = "mean") : missing values and Infs not allowed`

Can someone explain the nuance of these different "object" references within functions? I cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```r
data1 <- mtcars %>%
    select(mpg, cyl, map = map) %>%
    with(
      akima::interp(
        mpg, cyl, map,
        duplicate = "mean"
      )
    )
```

What we're doing here is renaming the selected variable (`wt`) to `map` on the fly, so that `akima::interp()` will work.

The problem is that, unlike tidyverse functions, `akima::interp` doesn't use any fancy non-standard evaluation. A perhaps more readable version would be

```r
data1 <- mtcars %>%
    select(mpg, cyl, map = map)
data1 <- akima::interp(data1$mpg, data1$cyl, data1[[map]], duplicate = "mean)
```

Comment: This did the trick. I knew it was something to do with the tidyverse function and interp using different evaluations, but I am relatively new to R and wasn't sure how to diagnose the issue. Are you aware of any good resources that explain NSE?

Answer (score 1):

You can subset `.` with `[[` when you are passing column names as string.

```
library(dplyr)
library(akima)

heat_map <- function(map){
  
  data1 <- mtcars %>%
    select(mpg, cyl, map) %>%
    with(
      akima::interp(
        mpg, cyl, .[[map]],
        duplicate = "mean"
      )
    )
  
  data2 <- data.frame(expand.grid(mpg = data1$x, cyl = data1$y), 
                      fill = c(data1$z))
  
  return(data2)
}


wt <- heat_map("wt")
```